# an elegant way to check for null

Tags: java, hibernate

Working with hibernate I use this sort of code many times:

```
int someId = entity.getSomething() == null ? null : entity.getSomething().getId();
```

This code becomes a little more messy when trying to apply on a longer hierarchy:

```
int someId = entity.getParent() == null ? null : 
entity.getParent().getParent() == null ? null :
entity.getParent().getParent().getSomething() == null ? null :
entity.getParent().getParent().getSomething().getId();
```

Is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: Java 8's `Optional.flatMap`, maybe.

Comment: You should avoid chaining method calls like `entity.getParent().getParent().getSomething().getId()`, because "talking to strangers" makes the code tightly coupled and thus harder to refactor. See also: [Law of Demeter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Comment: One other thing which helps: if your method has the invariant property that it never returns null, then you don't have to check it. Don't let things be nullable unless they really should be.

Answer (score 7):

As per Louis Wasserman's comment, `Optional` can almost be used as a NullObject a'la flogy's solution.

Using Java 8 `Optional` and lambdas it looks like this

```
Integer value = Optional.ofNullable(entity)
                        .map( Entity::getParent )
                        .map( Entity::getParent )
                        .map( Entity::getSomething )
                        .map( Something::getId )
                        .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Was slightly confused by this answer - using :: with nothing before it specifying the class doesn't compile right?

Comment: @755 Yep, you're right - looks like I was misremembering from another language where the type was inferred - sorry for the confusion. I've updated the answer to use the correct class names.

Answer (score 2):

In case those entity objects are written by yourself and not in a library, I would consider refactoring them and use [NullObjects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern). Like that you could then directly call

```
Integer someId = entity.getParent().getParent().getSomething().getId();
```

as this would then return your nulled integer.

Basically, it works like this:

1. entity.getParent() will return a NullParent instance
2. this NullParent class has a method getParent(), which also will return a NullParent instance
3. again, this NullParent class has a method getSomething(), which will return a NullSomething instance
4. the NullSomething class has a method getId(), which finally will return your nulled integer (e.g. 0 or another NullInteger object).

Here is an interesting post on [Why NULL is bad?](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/13/why-null-is-bad.html)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a more elegant way to do it?

You may simply go for try-catch for null check:

```
try{
  int id = entity.getParent().getParent().getSomething().getId();
  // do something with id
} catch(NullPointerException ex) {
  // got null
}
```

Comment: execption handling is a bad way of programming.

Comment: @UmaKanth, OP is looking for more readable code, I believe its a good practice instead of such ugly code blocks

Comment: Exceptions generate a stack trace, so if the null is a common case, then this could be very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Readability is very important factor as well as the simplification of code. It is better to use simple `if` condition here.

```
if(entity.getParent()!=null && entity.getParent().getParent() !=null && 
     entity.getParent().getParent().getSomething()!=null &&  
              entity.getParent().getParent().getSomething().getId()!=null){


}
```

And because of `&&`("short-circuit and"), if one condition `false` non other condition in the `right` execute.

Comment: I am sorry, but do you think this `if` construction is a readable thing ? :)

Comment: I agree with @RafaelOsipov, it's very hard to read this if construction

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the same `null` value if it's null.

Why don't you try giving it only if it is not null.

```
if(x != null)  x = y
```